# Unable to delete a contact from Salesforce

Tags: apex, custom-object, account, contact, delete

I have a user with custom profile and has access almost similar to System Admin. So when that user is trying to delete a contact, the following error is displayed on the screen

> **Your attempt to delete Test Contact could not be completed because
> it is associated with the following account.: Test Account**

I have deleted the Test account from lookup and even then, I am getting the same error. Also, that profile has all the permissions on contact and account starting from edit to modify all.

Wondering what's causing this error while deleting the contact.

Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315910&type=1&mode=1 follow the steps as mentioned in the article

Comment: @AbhishekMudireddy, I did went through this article and I didnt find that useful somehow. This error is not pointing to leads and there is no custom lookup field on Account to contact and vice versa. I only have lookup on contact to account and that related contact is deleted before trying to delete this contact. That didnt work as well

Comment: Do you have a custom lookup field in the Account object that is looking up to Contact, and is this lookup field set to "Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship"?